# Running tests in IntelliJ: cannot create JVM

Tags: intellij-idea

I am running IntelliJ version 13.1.3, on a 32 bit windows machine.
The JVM version is 1.7.
When running even simple tests, the following error is thrown:

```
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine. 
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit. 
Invalid maximum heap size: -Xmx4g 
The specified size exceeds the maximum representable size. 
Process finished with exit code 1
```

Can anyone assist?
Thanks

Comment: Fix maximum heap size, 32 bit supports max ~900MB

Comment: Thanks. Where is this set in IntelliJ ?

Comment: Probably in your Run Configuration https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/creating-and-editing-run-debug-configurations.html

Comment: Setting -Xmx512m in both the run configuration for the test, and the idea.exea.vmpotions file, has not helped - same issue

Comment: well, you have a setting somewhere that's doing this. Try grepping across your file system for `-Xmx4g`

Answer (score 0):

Pycharm that stands on the intellij has the jvm configuration file with this name:

```
pycharm.exe.vmoptions
```

Maybe you can find similar file in the binary path of intellij to change the jvm heap properties.

Answer (score 0):

Comment from Engineer Dollery is correct. I found this in my POM file. I just commented out and the then I was able to run the test.

```
<!--<argLine>-Xms128m -Xmx4096m -XX:MaxPermSize=128m</argLine>-->
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to file.
2. Select Project Structure.
3. Choose Project Settings then Select Project
4. There You can see Project language level
5. Just put it back to 8.
6. Project language level is changed in new update of InteliJ update thats why This error Occurs

Now just try to run your Code.